# Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom - Ajax Call Magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax

I have implemented Ajax call to add product to cart, which is somewhat like below:

```
$.ajax({
    showLoader: true,
    url: SERVER_URL+'common/custompurchase/addtocart',
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    // some code...
});
```

It is working fine. But it's not showing loading icon when i call Ajax. I have also tried below answers.

1. `$('body').trigger('processStart');`
2. `$('body').loader('show');`
3. `var body = $('body').loader(); body.loader('show');`

In console it's showing this warning.

> Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom

Please provide suggestions if anybody has faced such issue.

**Note:** I have implemented this code on product detail page.

Comment: Its a default Magento bug you can check this issue on GIT :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11904

Comment: but i have also coded ajax call for some other tasks on different pages. there it works fine. only on this page it does not work.

Comment: Can you please add the screen when you call ajax?

Answer (score 5):

To prevent console log error use Magento default function **processStart** and **processStop** for the loader in your ajax.

> remove this from your ajax call **showLoader: true**

```
 $.ajax(
         /*showLoader: true, Remove this one */
         url: url,
         data: param,
         type: "POST",
         beforeSend: function () {
             $('body').trigger('processStart'); // start loader
         }
         }).done(function (data) {
             $('body').trigger('processStop');   // stop loader
             return true;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

By adding the following HTML code before the ajax call. make sure it renders between `<body>` and `</body>`tag

```
<body>   
<div class="loading-mask" data-role="loader">
    <div class="loader"> &nbsp;        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```